# VMWare Player Same Origin Policy simulation environment

Tags: cross-browser, cross-domain, xss, same-origin-policy, vmware-player

I am writing a report on XSHM (Cross-Site History Manipulation). XSHM basically resolves around SOP (Same Origin Policy).

I am trying to perform tests on SOP using virtual environments and using different web browsers.

However, I am struggling to set up VmWare Player machines to listen on different domains, going through my local machine. Basically, I want to  fool the browser to think 'machineA.com' is completely different website on different network to 'machineB.com' so I can perform experiments on the 'Same Origin Policy'

My question is any ideas on how this can be achieved. NOTE - I have thought about setting up a netkit environment with different DNS servers but I need a graphical interface so I can test web browsers by creating vulnerable test apps.

Would really appreciate any ideas on how to set up this kind of environment

Answer (score 0):

Set up your VMWare machines to use "bridged" Ethernet connections, which will give them each their own IP address.

On the machine running the browser, edit [/etc/hosts](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap9sec95.html) to map those IP addresses to different domains.  Then you can access the player machines using those (different) domain names.